# Accessing files on google colab

Tags: conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, style-transfer

i'm using Google Colaboratory IPython to do style transfer, after mounting my drive by running:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/drive')
```

It was mounted, so i tried to cd into a directory, show the pwd and ls but it doesn't display the correct pwd

```
!cd "/content/drive/My Drive/"
!pwd
!ls
```

but it won't cd into the directory given, it only cd into 'content/'

also when i tried accessing some images using a "load_image() function in my code like below

```
def load_image(img_path, max_size=400, Shape=None):
    image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
    if max(image.size) > max_size:
        size = max_size
    else:
        size = max(image.size)

    if shape is not None:
        size = shape

    in_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(size),
                    transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize((0.485, 0.456, 0.406), 
                                         (0.229, 0.224, 0.225))])

    image = in_transform(image)[:3,:,:].unsqueeze(0)

    return image
#load image content
content = load_image('content/drive/My Drive/uche.jpg')
style = load_image('content/drive/My Drive/uche.jpg')
```

But this code throws an error when i tried to load image from the directory saying:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content/drive/My Drive/uche.jpg'

Comment: I wonder if, when I've removed the "ML" tag from enough questions, the network will eventually learn that it's a family of programming languages. (The only relevant tag seems to be "google-colaboratory". Don't spam tags.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: To change the working directory, use `%cd` or `os.chdir` rather than `!cd`.

The back-story is that `!` commands are executed in a subshell, with its own independent working directory from the Python process running your code. But, what you want is to change the working directory of the Python process. That's what `os.chdir` will do, and `%cd` is a convenient alias that works in notebooks.

Putting it together, I think you want to write:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd /content/drive/My\ Drive
```